# Loading gsdll64.dll from (a) GhostScriptAPI suddenly throws BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ghostscript

I installed GhostScript 9.19 x64 a month or so ago to use in a .NET 4 Web Application and it has been working great ever since.

After a recent source control checkin (first one since installing GS), my GhostScriptAPI wrapper is now throwing a **`BadImageFormatException`**

[image]

```
[DllImport("c:\\gsdll64.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern int gsapi_new_instance(out IntPtr lngGSInstance, IntPtr lngCallerHandle);

intReturn = gsapi_new_instance(out intGSInstanceHandle, callerHandle);
```

Even though the application is configured to target *"Any CPU"*, it will fail to load with a `BadImageFormatException` if *x64* is explicitly set, so it is in fact targeting *x86*.

[image]

I realize that I need to use the *x86* version of GhostScript (gsdll32.dll) or to get my app to run on *x64*, however my question is **how was GhostScript working beforehand while my app and it were targeting two different platforms** (luck, magic, divine intervention)?

Comment: There is a flag for "prefer 32-bit", see if it is checked.

Comment: Just a gentle nudge here, you are aware of the fact that Ghostscript is AGPL licensed ?

Comment: @KenS Do I appear to be in violation?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Prefer 32-bit is unchecked and disabled (thanks). I just added WIN32/WIN64 conditional flags and noticed that, while targeting Any CPU, the code in the `#if WIN32` branch is all grayed-out. So now I'm suspecting that by default VS wants to target x64 (my machine and OS are x64), and thinks it's going to, but then maybe runs into something at build time that forces it to switch to x86. This "switch", however, must happen after the preprocessor since `#if WIN32` fails, or  the conditional flags are never updated after it occurs.

Comment: Samus, I don't know, it depends on what you are doing with your application. Not enough details for me to tell, but I thought it was worth a mention, if you're planning on distributing your application, or selling it.

Comment: @KenS Is for factory printing, not commercial software.